# Datepicker always visible

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, cordova, datepicker

[image: Date Picker]

In my phonegap app I created a datepicker field. For this one I used jquery-ui-datepicker plugin and didn't write any action in my javascript file.

My problem is the date picker is visible always, but I want to show it when I click the date field and hide it when the date is selected.

my html code:

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-hide-label">
    <label for="mDOB">DOB</label>
    <input type="date" name="date" id="date" value=""  />   
</div>
```

and my datepicker ui code:

```
(function($, undefined ) {

//cache previous datepicker ui method
var prevDp = $.fn.datepicker;

//rewrite datepicker
$.fn.datepicker = function( options ){

    var dp = this;

    //call cached datepicker plugin
    prevDp.call( this, options );

    //extend with some dom manipulation to update the markup for jQM
    //call immediately
    function updateDatepicker(){
    $( ".ui-datepicker-header", dp ).addClass("ui-body-c ui-corner-top").removeClass("ui-corner-all");
    $( ".ui-datepicker-prev, .ui-datepicker-next", dp ).attr("href", "#");
    $( ".ui-datepicker-prev", dp ).buttonMarkup({iconpos: "notext", icon: "arrow-l", shadow: true, corners: true});
    $( ".ui-datepicker-next", dp ).buttonMarkup({iconpos: "notext", icon: "arrow-r", shadow: true, corners: true});
    $( ".ui-datepicker-calendar th", dp ).addClass("ui-bar-c");
    $( ".ui-datepicker-calendar td", dp ).addClass("ui-body-c");
    $( ".ui-datepicker-calendar a", dp ).buttonMarkup({corners: false, shadow: false}); 
    $( ".ui-datepicker-calendar a.ui-state-active", dp ).addClass("ui-btn-active"); // selected date
    $( ".ui-datepicker-calendar a.ui-state-highlight", dp ).addClass("ui-btn-up-e"); // today"s date
        $( ".ui-datepicker-calendar .ui-btn", dp ).each(function(){
    var el = $(this);
    // remove extra button markup - necessary for date value to be interpreted correctly
    el.html( el.find( ".ui-btn-text" ).text() ); 
    }); 
};

//update now
updateDatepicker();

// and on click
$( dp ).click( updateDatepicker );

//return jqm obj 
eturn this;
};

//bind to pagecreate to automatically enhance date inputs   
$( ".ui-page" ).live( "pageshow", function(){       
    $( "input[type='date'], input:jqmData(type='date')", this ).each(function(){
    $(this).after( $( "<div />" ).datepicker({ altField: "#" + $(this).attr( "id" ), showOtherMonths: true }) );
        }); 
    });
})( jQuery );
```

Suggest some solution or give some example date pickers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initializing the datepicker on a DIV makes it always visible, and initializing the datepicker on an input makes it pop up when the input is focused, right now you're creating a new DIV element that the datepicker is initialized on, and that DIV is then inserted after() the input.
Try removing that DIV and initialize the datepicker directly on the input :

```
$( "input[type='date'], input:jqmData(type='date')", this ).each(function(){
    $(this).datepicker({ altField: "#" + $(this).attr( "id" ), showOtherMonths: true });
});
```

Comment: Sounds like a styling issue, but not sure ?